# Using column as table join with concat

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

I've been trying to join another table with the table name matching a value in a column from another table.

If I hard-code the table name to a matching table like `__gun` it works fine but I cannot get the col value to be used + concat underscores to the beginning.

The problem lies in the `left join` here:

`left join CONCAT('__', b.related_table) c on b.related_id = c.id`

I need the related_table column to be used in the join. With __ before it.

*Attempts:*

```
        SELECT a.*, c.*, b.equipable, b.related_table FROM inventory a
        inner join items b on a.item_id = b.id
        left join CONCAT('__', b.related_table) c on b.related_id = c.id
        WHERE 1=1
        and a.id = :inventory_id
        and a.user_id = :user_id
```

[image]

---

```
        SELECT a.*, c.*, b.equipable, b.related_table FROM inventory a
        inner join items b on a.item_id = b.id
        left join '__'+b.related_table c on b.related_id = c.id
        WHERE 1=1
        and a.id = :inventory_id
        and a.user_id = :user_id
```

[image]

---

```
        SELECT a.*, c.*, b.equipable, b.related_table FROM inventory a
        inner join items b on a.item_id = b.id
        left join "__"+Cast(b.related_table as nvarchar(4000)) c on b.related_id = c.id
        WHERE 1=1
        and a.id = :inventory_id
        and a.user_id = :user_id
```

[image]

Thank you for considering my question

Comment: FROM takes table name literals or subselects. It seems likely that this is a poor design. [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot construct a table name.

Plan A:  Rethink the schema.  It is *usually* bad design to have multiple 'identical' tables.

Plan B:  Write a Stored Procedure that uses `CONCAT`, `PREPARE`, `EXECUTE`, and `DEALLOCATE_PREPARE` to build and run the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) or you can say dynamic SQL. Follow these steps :

1. Use *SET* for table name.
2. Use *CONCAT* to get the desired table name.
3. *PREPARE* statement for table created at step 1.
4. *EXECUTE* statement.
5. *DEALLOCATE PREPARE* to release the prepared statement.